# Классы и дефолтная инициализация

Tags: c#

В C# в структурах запрещено использовать конструктор без параметров, так как он используется для инициализации членов структуры (обнуления выделяемой памяти). Также в структурах мы обязаны инициализировать все поля структуры в случае определения конструктора с параметрами. Но в классах ни первое, ни второе не обязательно. Как тогда в классах работает инициализация полей класса дефолтными значениями?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все поля типов значений инициализируются значениями по умолчанию (`0` для `System.Int32`, например), все поля ссылочных типов инициализируются нулевыми ссылками (`null`).

Comment: Да, это понятно, но каким образом это происходит, если мы к примеру переопределяем дефолтный конструктор и сами не инициализируем некоторые из полей класса?

Comment: Все непроинициализированные вручную поля будут проинициализированы значениями по умолчанию, прежде чем конструктор вернёт созданный объект.

Comment: почему тогда так не происходит с полями структуры?

Comment: На enSO есть подобный вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721246 Если коротко - чтобы сразу можно было инициализировать поля значениями, а не тратить дополнительное время на обнуление памяти под структуру.

Comment: Т.е. если обобщить в классах есть проверка, проинициализированны поля или нет, и если нет, по происходит инициализация дефолтными значениями. В структурах этого нет в целях повышения перформанса и необходима явная инициализация всех полей?

Comment: Если в общем и целом, да. Экземпляры ссылочных типов размещаются в управляемой куче, где обнуление памяти гарантировано. С областью стека, где часто размещаются экземпляры типов значений, такой гарантии нет. Чтобы не обнулять память лишний раз, производится сразу полная инициализация.

Answer (score 1):

Значения полей класса инициализируются [значениями по умолчанию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table).

Например,

```
public class TestClass
{
   public int _int;
   public string _string;
}

TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
int i = testClass._int; //0
string s = testClass._string; //null
```